# Nvidia RTX ray tracing OpenGL extension

Tags: opengl, raytracing, nvidia

I can't seem to find any OpenGL headers for the RTX ray tracing extension, seems like they only want you to use Vulkan and optix with RTX

Answer (score 4):

Is your question whether or not OpenGL headers exist for the RTX extension?
[It appears it can only be accessed through NVIDIA OptiX, DXR, and Vulkan.](https://developer.nvidia.com/rtx/raytracing)

From the website:

> Developers can access NVIDIA RTX ray tracing through the NVIDIA OptiX application programming interface, through Microsoft’s DirectX Raytracing API (DXR) and Vulkan.

Comment: I was looking for an OpenGL extension for RTX but I guess it not available just yet

Answer (score -1):

There's an extension already, though I'm not sure how finished it is: **[GLSL_NV_raytracing](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/master/extensions/nv/GLSL_NV_ray_tracing.txt)**.

Comment: Vladislav is right, however the hyperlink address misses, could be found here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/master/extensions/nv/GLSL_NV_ray_tracing.txt

Comment: @Alex I've converted your answer to a comment, and edited your fixed link into Vladislav Toncharov's answer.

Comment: This is a GLSL extension, not an OpenGL extension.  It is for use with Vulkan.